# Angular.js Tutorial using the Node.js webserver

Tags: javascript, git, node.js, angularjs

I am trying to go through the [Angular.js Tutrorial_00](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00) and cannot seem to work out how to get the node.js web server to run the demo app?

Has anyone done this tutorial or know how correctly use this step to get the server working?

1. For node.js users: In a separate terminal tab or window, run `node scripts\web-server.js` to start the web server. Open a browser window
2. for the app and navigate to `http://localhost:8000/app/index.html`

What happens is that I run step 1 in node.js and then it outputs "...", which I assum means it is listening.

Then when I get to step 2 I type that in the browser and get "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to ".

Comment: What happens when you try following the instructions?

Comment: In node.js instance I run "node scripts\web-server.js"
In chrome I nav to "http://localhost:8000/app/index.html"
I get a "Webpage is not avaliable"
The project is in C:\Users\Owain\angular-phonecat\app
I not sure how the server will know to access this location to sever up content? @Quentin

Comment: What is "node.js instance"?

Comment: When you run "node scripts\web-server.js", what is the output at the console?

Comment: *"I not sure how the server will know to access this location to sever up content?"* - If you're doing it right then "because that is what web-server.js is designed to do".

Comment: node.js is just the command window

Comment: The output is just "..." on a new line

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`node scripts\web-server.js` is a command line, not a piece of JavaScript.

Run it in a shell (on Windows that probably means PowerShell) while making sure you are in the right directory. Don't try to run it in a node REPL.

Comment: Thanks, ran in command prompt & changed to correct directory. Worked!

Comment: what is the correct directory ??

Comment: @AbdurRahman — the one the path is relative to

Comment: @Quentin: I've setup nodejs with default settings.. could you please specify where could I find the web-server.js file.. I've searched into the entire C drive and found a couple of file with same name in appdata folder..

Comment: No, I have no idea where you installed it to and I don't use Windows.

Comment: @Quentin: I ran the command from command line but it shows this error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\scripts\web-server.js'

Comment: scripts\web-server.js is at where you have installed angularJS

Comment: Google's Angular tutorial misses a step. After you get the Windows command line window up, you'll have something like C:\Users\YourName> If you have followed prior instructions, the missing step after the Step 1 checkout is  cd angular-phonecat  This gets you into the correct directory that you previously cloned. Then enter  node scripts\web-server.js  You will get a "Server running at . . ." message. The guys above who closed this as "not a real question" don't live in the real world. It is a specific question about how beginners do a tutorial, that has incomplete instructions.